# Global application context/environment runtime properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

There are some properties which are not read from a configuration file but are acquired from some remote resources and are constant, for example, user ID from a database. They are **global in app context** (it means that each application context has same properties with different values).

I expected something like `context.setProperty` or `context.setGlobalProperty` or `context.getEnvironment().setProperty`, but I couldn't find such methods.

My current solution is to create a singleton lazy bean which is initialized during application initialization and then it can be autowired into any bean. But it seems to me that this is not the best method.

Comment: You cannot set anything on the `Environment` you need to add your own `PropertySource` using an `ApplicationContextInitializer`. Or get the properties before calling `SpringApplication.run` and use the builder approach on the `SpringApplication` to set the default properties.

Comment: @M. Deinum The problem is that in order to initialize some properties I need some beans to be constructed, for example, a specific DAO. In order to construct DAO I need to build and run app context. Now I think I have to create some parent context which initializes global properties (again, global per context, not per JVM), then to create child contexts with initialized environment variables. Is that good idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to change environment during runtime.
Environment is also bean in context, so your solution is ok.
Also you can use static container with dynamic variables and fill it during runtime